# Failing over to DR site Availability group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, windows, disaster-recovery, failover-cluster-instance

I have a 4 node cluster SQL 2012 availability group database with one witness server at the primary site. 3 nodes are in the primary site and one node in the DR site.

Due to maintenance at the Primary Site I need to failover to the DR site and making it as the primary.

Here is my question, if I Failover to the Dr Site and turn off all the nodes one by one gracefully including the witness server, will the Dynamin Quorum take over and keep the cluster and the availability group alive or the Windows Server Failover Cluster goes down and AG is inaccessible and as a result I will have to bring the cluster service up with force quorum

Answer (score 0):

> I have a 4 node cluster SQL 2012 availability group database with one witness server at the primary site. 3 nodes are in the primary site and one node in the DR site.

Pedantically, if you have a 4 node cluster with 3 nodes and 1 node, then you don't have a witness server. I don't know what your witness is, if any.

> Here is my question, if I Failover to the Dr Site and turn off all the nodes one by one gracefully including the witness server, will the Dynamin Quorum take over and keep the cluster and the availability group alive or the Windows Server Failover Cluster goes down and AG is inaccessible and as a result I will have to bring the cluster service up with force quorum

While it's possible to make this work, it requires a setup that you're not currently running since there will be a communications failure between nodes. Should there be a proper witness setup that has communications even when the primary site is down, you can move the core cluster resources to the node in your DR and then shut down the other nodes one by one and achieve this. Since I doubt this is your architecture, most likely it won't work that way.

Comment: I have a witness serve located at the primary site.  My plan was to make the DR site primary and move the cluster resource there and then turn off all the nodes at the primary one by one and achieve dynamic quorum and which will enable the Node at the DR site to be online (last man standing)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you have DR node in Synchronous mode. If it is in A-sync, change it first to avoid data loss. When your primary node will be in DR dc, you can shout down all others nodes also witness. AG will be still available on the last active node. Of course you will get alerts that AG is not ready for automatic failover (if it is configured like that) etc.

When you start the other nodes again, you need to wait util they become in sync to do fail back.

Also keep an eye on the transaction log as it may grow when other nodes are down.